# phantomjs not honouring box-sizing

Tags: css, phantomjs, yui-pure-css

I'm using phantomjs (1.9.8) to get screenshots for a project. This project uses [Pure CSS grids](http://purecss.io/grids/) for responsive layout. Here is a stripped down HTML demo for what I'm doing:

http://output.jsbin.com/sobabiy/1

This is what phantomjs sees (viewport 1024x768):
[image]

I'm a little rusty on my CSS skills, but my gut feeling is that somehow

```
box-sizing: border-box
```

isn't being taken in account, and the last node "drops" down. What other options do I have here?

Comment: Please read more about box-sizing to understand if that's causing your issue: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Comment: I assume it's the case, because without declaring it as border-box, the last node drops down in a same fashion on all modern browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently upgrading to phantomjs 2.0 solved the problem.